# what is the mean of that kind of int type in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

Can anyone explain what is the mean of int[][] that can be used to calculate the operations of converting String1 to String2.

```
 public int editDistanceDP(String s1, String s2) {
        int [][] ds = new int[s1.length()+1][s2.length()+1];



for (int i = 0; i <=s1.length(); i++) {//all elements will be removed
    ds[i][0] =i;
}

for (int i = 0; i <=s2.length(); i++) {//all elements will be inserted
    ds[0][i] =i;


  public static void main(String() args){
   String s1 = hello;
   String s2 = hi;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any connection between int[][] and conversion of one string to another. Perhaps you should add the code you have trouble with.

Comment: provide code what you makes confusing.

Comment: Judging by the little code you posted and the comments in the code I guess the 2 column array is to be used as a key to which letters to use when merging the strings into one. I believe the result is “hillo”.

Comment: Please provide code that *compiles*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this called arrays in java [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> You can also declare an array of arrays (also known as a multidimensional array) by using two or more sets of brackets, such as String[][] names. Each element, therefore, must be accessed by a corresponding number of index values.

Type can be any thing, in your case its `int`.

**Can be used to calculate the operations of converting String1 to String2??**
This is specific problem how you are converting and what you want to do with this array it upto you.

Comment: I knew int[] means an array, so int[][] means two arrays there?

Comment: No.  It is an array of arrays.

Comment: @TIGUZI please read the tutorial link in the answer and from more details read https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-java/0596009208/apb.html#hash2_multidimensional_arrays